# jquery read more toggle button works with only one blog post.

Tags: jquery, toggle, show-hide

Im having trouble getting my jQuery button to work. It's my first hands on experience with it so go easy on me.

Currently the button works... but only when i have "ONE" blog post. As its wordpress and the site will have multiple posts my button doesn't really work.

Here is the code for my post.

```
                   <div id="blog_posts">
                        <?php query_posts ('posts_per_page=5&paged='.get_query_var('paged')); ?>  
                        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

                        <div class="post-wrap blog">

                            <div class="post-thumbnail">
                                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="blog-block2">
                                <div class="post-title blog">
                                    <?php the_title(); ?>
                                </div>
                                <div class="post-meta blog">
                                    <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/inc/meta.php' ); ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="post-content blog">
                                <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                <a id="read-more-blog" class="read-more">read more...</a>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            <div id="blog-content-more" class="post-content-more blog">
                                <?php the_content(); ?>
                                <a id="read-less-blog" class="read-less">read less...</a>
                                <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                        </div>
```

Here is the code for my Jquery button (below) that hides the read more text button and displays the blog-content-more div. The button also displays the read less text button and when that is clicked hides the div that just popped out.

```
//BLOG TOGGLE BUTTON : READ MORE
$( "#read-more-blog" ).click(function() {

    $( "#read-more-blog" ).toggle( "slow");

    var this_blog = $( "#read-more-blog" );

        if ($("#blog-content-more:visible").length == 0){

            this_blog.addClass('clicked');  
        }
            else
        {
            this_blog.removeClass('clicked');
        }

    $( "#blog-content-more" ).toggle( "slow");
});


//BLOG TOGGLE BUTTON : READ LESS
$( "#read-less-blog" ).click(function() {
  $( "#blog-content-more" ).toggle( "slow" );
  $( "#read-more-blog" ).toggle( "slow");
});
```

so my question is... how do i get my jquery button to work when there are multiple versions of the html on my page?

Iv been looking into parent and sibling syntax's but been scratching my head on this.

Hope someone can help. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand correctly you have a set of buttons for each post, 
if so you would need to rely on [class](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) attribute that would be assigned to all the buttons

like in this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/sN3Wk/

```
$( ".read-more, .read-less" ).click(function() {});
```

there are nicer ways to access the elements but you the main idea is that you have to think in a generic way

Answer (score 0):

Replace all ID's in blog_posts div with classes and try this:

```
$( ".read-less-blog" ).click(function() {
   var $this = $(this);
   $this.find(".blog-content-more").toggle( "slow" );
   $this.find(".read-more-blog").toggle( "slow");
});
```

Same thing for read-more-blog.

Comment: have a look at the fiddle below

Comment: Thanks Bill'o! I understand the generic thinking part just was not sure how to implement it. Thanks for the foundations to progress!